# Issue copying sheets in excel

Tags: excel, vba

i am writting a code to copy a sheet in excel from one workbook to another and I'm having the following issue :

```
 Set xlsAppSource = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
 Set xlsWBSource = xlsAppSource.Workbooks.Open(strWBSource)  

 Set xlsAppCible = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
 Set xlsWBCible = xlsAppCible.Workbooks.Open(strWBCible)

 xlsWBSource.Sheets(1).Copy before:= xlsWBSource.Sheets(1)
```

And I get `ERROR 1004`.

I know the error comes from :

`xlsWBSource.Sheets(1)` and `xlsWBSource.Sheets(1)`

because when change the last statement to :

```
xlsWBSource.activate

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(strSheetSource).Copy before:= [any working sheet]
```

it works.

But As I cannot activate the 2 workbooks it's not a way to solve my problem.

Any ideas why it doesnt work ?

thanks

Comment: Are you sure this is right? `xlsWBSource.Sheets(1).Copy before:= xlsWBSource.Sheets(1)` Aren't you trying to copy from `xlsWBSource` to `xlsWBCible`?

Comment: @brettdj I'm pretty new to VB, but I'm just trying to copy the sheets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are tring to copy from from `xlsWBSource` to `xlsWBCible` then you should only use one [instance of Excel](http://faqexcel.blogspot.com/2007/03/instance.html) , you are currently opening two separate versions with your two `CreateObjects` - the two separate instances can't "talk", hence the error

Whereas this will work:

```
Set xlsAppSource = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlsWBSource = xlsAppSource.Workbooks.Open(strWbsource)
Set xlsWBcible = xlsAppSource.Workbooks.Open(strWBcible)
xlsWBSource.Sheets(1).Copy before:=xlsWBcible.Sheets(1)
```